# crash with CoUnintailize() api of COM

Tags: c++, c, windows, com, ado

My main process(main.exe) initilaized COM library and created a thread which creates a new process(p1.exe) this new process is again initializing COM library and after making all references as zero unintialized COM here.. the unintailezed COM in the main process (i.e main.exe) also....

When i run p1.exe individually it is successful.. but it is crashing when i create a process for p1.exe from main.exe

Comment: Can you post some sample code that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CoInitializeEx()?
You should youse CoInitializeEx with COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED.